# How to write a single SQL query to single out a subgroup with several conditions regarding the number of feature and priority of the features

Tags: sql

I have this `table`:

[image]

I need to get this `table`:

[image]

One class should correspond to one id. The class is selected as follows:

1. the most common `class` for id is chosen (for example, id 222 corresponds to class C).
2. If the number of classes is equal (as for id 111), then class is selected in accordance with the priority system (B is better C, C is better A).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most databases, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select ic.*
from (select id, class, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by count(*) desc,
                                         (case class when 'B' then 1 when 'C' then 2 when 'A' then 3 else 4 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
      group by id, class
     ) ic
where seqnum = 1;
```